# Scalar-valued function returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below function, and for the life of me, I cannot get it to return a value, I get NULL every time.

I am calling it via `select [dbo].[getFiatProfit](600.26,'GBP', 1000.99,'BTC') as op`

What am I missing?

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[getFiatProfit]    Script Date: 06/07/2022 11:42:26 ******/
   
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getFiatProfit] (
        @fiatInvested float,
        @fiatInvestedCurrency nvarchar,
        @quantity float,
        @currency nvarchar
    )
    RETURNS float
    AS
    BEGIN
        declare @tmp float
        declare @result float
        declare @usdtgbp float
        IF (@fiatInvestedCurrency = 'USD')
            BEGIN
                select @tmp = [dbo].[usdtPairs].[Value] from [dbo].[usdtPairs] where usdtPairs.ID = @currency;
                select @usdtgbp = [dbo].[usdtPairs].[Value] from [dbo].[usdtPairs] where usdtPairs.ID = 'GBP';
                set @result = (((@quantity * @tmp) - @fiatInvested) / @usdtgbp);
                -- set @result = @quantity * @tmp;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                select @tmp = [dbo].[usdtPairs].[Value] from [dbo].[usdtPairs] where usdtPairs.ID = @currency;
                set @result = ((@quantity * @tmp) - @fiatInvested);
                -- set @result = @quantity * @tmp;
            END
    return (@result)
    END
```

Comment: We can't run your query, so this is very difficult to debug. Also, however, multiline scalar functions can perform very poorly; even if you are on SQL Server 2019+ the above is unlikely to be inlinable. An inline table value function would be significantly more performant. You are also using 3+ naming for your columns; this is to be deprecated and should be avoided. Alias your objects and use those to qualify your columns.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: Declaring varchar without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). The default length in most circumstances is 1 so your currencies are `G` and `B`, not `GBP` and `BTC`.

Comment: Careful. You assume that queries like `select @tmp = [dbo].[usdtPairs].[Value] from [dbo].[usdtPairs] where ...` retrieve a single row. Is that safe? Are you certain? Better to use SET to guarantee an error when multiple rows are retrieved IMO.

Comment: Just to confirm what @Damien_The_Unbeliever has said, the exact same function returns a value when the parameters are properly defined. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8f084aa70979eb0844fb4c49a37d809)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue looks it's because your parameters are declared without a length. `nvarchar` [defaults to a length of `1`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) in a lot of circumstances, so it's simply the wrong value being received. A much better data type would be `char(3)` which is fixed length, given that all currencies have exact three-letter names.

You should also convert this function into a Table Valued Function, which is likely to perform far better.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getFiatProfit (
    @fiatInvested float,
    @fiatInvestedCurrency char(3),
    @quantity float,
    @currency char(3)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
  result = ((@quantity * u.Value) - @fiatInvested)
    / (CASE WHEN @fiatInvestedCurrency = 'USD'
        THEN 1
        ELSE
          (SELECT u2.Value FROM dbo.usdtPairs u2 WHERE u2.ID = 'GBP')
       END)
FROM dbo.usdtPairs u
WHERE u.ID = @currency;
```

You use it like this

```
SELECT t.*, fp.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY dbo.getFiatProfit(t.fiatInvested, t.fiatInvestedCurrency, t.Qty, 'GBP') fp;
```

Comment: I'm using the function within a computed column, would this still be more performant?

Comment: You can't use TVFs in computed columns. But in any case using these types of functions in computed columns has consistency issues, see eg https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/another-reason-why-scalar-functions-in-computed-columns-is-a-bad-idea/ and others. A better idea would be a view, possibly an indexed view if performance is an issue